# What function does "just red" have?

Tags: syntax, parts-of-speech

> If you have steak you can eat it rare; medium-rare (cooked a bit longer
>   and just **red** in the middle)...

What is the role of "red" in this sentence? Is it a noun or an adjective?

What function does the expression "just red" have — is it like an adverb for cooking or something?

Comment: *rare*? I'm finding it hard to understand the sentence. Or it's red...a medium-red?

Comment: You haven't provided the entire sentence. Please don't ask if a sentence is grammatically correct unless you at least provide the entire sentence. You can find more tips [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439). (If you want, you can edit the question to provide more context, and ask about grammatical correctness.)

Comment: Oh, I thought you **explained** the phrase *medium-rare* in the brackets in your own words! Well, still... red is adjective there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *red* in this parenthetical statement is an adjective; it simply refers to the middle of the steak being cooked long enough to be "just red" in the middle, like the steak in the bottom left corner:

[image]

<sub>Image from [Steak Buenos Aires](http://steakbuenosaires.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/doneness_chart2.jpg)</sub>

Comment: i don't know if i can express myself correctly here but i mean how you use the part "just red" in the sentence - is it like an adverb for cook or something ?

Comment: Ah! Good question. Check out meanings 9, 10, 11, 12 at [this dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/just). So, _just red_ could mean "a little red" (def. 12) or "precisely red – not reddish-pink" (def. 11). I think what it means in this context – _just red in the middle_ – is "only red in the middle, not red all the way through" (def. 10). Worded another way: looking at the picture, a medium rare steak is red **only in the middle**, but a rare steak is red **almost all the way through**.